# Why did Darlene put fentanyl in the drugs for the cartel?

Tags: plot-explanation, ozark

Why did Darlene put fentanyl in the drugs for the cartel in *Ozark*? I can't work out what she is gaining by ruining the drugs, surely this would just ruin the Snell's reputation as a supplier (S2 Episode 8).
Also would this have had the consent of her husband?

Comment: Hello! I need to rewatch it, before I could more solidly answer, but Darline does a lot of stuff in spite, rather than logically dealing with any situation. I think she even admits to this about herself after her rash reaction in killing Dell.

Comment: Did you finish the season?

Comment: Yes I did however she didn't give a proper reason in the part before they go to bed just "send a message to the cartel". Maybe to stop the casino? Not sure how if she wanted and knew that it would trace back to her however. I also don't understand why she kills Mr Snell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after a quick rewatch of the season, **what Darlene *thinks* she is gaining, is setting up the Mexican Drug Cartel for failure and prove that they can't take advantage of them**, as some of their clients become ill and even die after taking the drug, which also then **blows back onto Marty and Wendy**. Most of their clients probably don't know that the Snells are one of their suppliers, however the FBI quickly figures that out, because of the location of where people dying are (Chicago and the Ozarks) make it easier for them to pinpoint the source.

**2.08 Transcript**

> DARLENE: Is something bothering you?
>
> JACOB: As a matter of fact there is.
>
> DARLENE: Should I make you some cocoa?
>
> JACOB: It was you wasn't it? You spiked the product.
>
> DARLENE: What if I did?
>
> JACOB: You know how many people you've hurt?
>
> **DARLENE: Ugh! Some junkies who were killing themselves with dope
>   succeeded. So what? This is about respect. The cartel thought they
>   could roll right over us. Well, they don't anymore.**
>
> JACOB: I think you misconstrue the situation.
>
> DARLENE: I told you not to get involved with them.
>
> JACOB: I don't answer to you, Darlene.
>
> DARLENE: I think you misconstrue the situation.
>
> JACOB: They'll come after us. There'll be a war.
>
> DARLENE: We've had to fight before. I am not afraid. Are you?
>
> **JACOB: Yes, I am. I am afraid. Of you and your implacable rage. Your
>   rashness.**
>
> **DARLENE: You killed Ash for no reason**. For money, for a casino.
>
> JACOB: I killed him to save you.
>
> DARLENE: I guess we just see things differently.

One has to remember from the beginning that Darlene never wanted to make this deal, but becomes furious when Dell comes to their house, as she finds his manner completely disrespectful. Even though she acknowledges that killing Dell may have been a little rash, **she continues to use the argument of disresepct in conjunction to "The Snell way". The more immediate reason Darlene put the fentanyl in the heroin was reprisal for Jacob trying to make amends to the Cartell** once they learned about what really happened Dell, **when he killed Ash**. Darlene viewed Ash as family and though his death was unnecessary, despite they would of all died otherwise. **Darlene is not a logical person**, which become more evident when she begs god to save Jacob after he was shot, only to turn around in the next episode and

> kills Jacob herself!